# how to solve this paramiko import issue?

Tags: paramiko, pycrypto

I have an issue with installing paramiko.. I think It is installed correctly from pip and when I tried to do import paramiko... I got an error..

```
us159010:site-packages jaehokim00$ python
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.


 import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "paramiko/transport.py", line 49, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "paramiko/dsskey.py", line 26, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA 
ImportError: No module named Crypto.PublicKey
```

I also reinstalled on pycrypto again. My python version is 2.6 and os is Mac OS 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

I got this somehow when I install crypto it shows crypto and paramiko is looking for **Crypto**

I had to change site-package directory for crypto to Crypto and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I have just got the same error message. I've solved it following these steps.

At its [official doc](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko) says, paramiko needs [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) and [ecdsa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ecdsa) packages.
to start with, you need python-dev package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Then install pycrypto. Here is the package [download](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/releases), it is better to choose the last release, build it an install it:

- go to pycrypto extraction dir
- `python setup.py build`
- `python setup.py install`

Do the same thing for `ecdsa`, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa/releases).

Here you go !

Answer (score 0):

As for me what worked in OS X is:

`brew uninstall python
brew install python
pip install -r requirements.txt
aka: pip install crypto pycrypto Fabric paramiko`

in terminal this was not the fastest strategy possibly but it did work.